# What are guarantees for concurrent writes into a named pipe?

Tags: linux, pipe

For example, I created a named pipe like the following:

```
mknod myPipe p
```

And I read from it from some process (for example, some server). For example purposes, I used tail:

```
tail -f myPipe
```

If several client processes write some messages into it (for example, `echo "msg" >> myPipe`, is there some chance that messages will get interleaved, like this:

```
 <beginning of message1><message2><ending of message1>
```

Or is the process of writing to named pipe is atomic?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It depends on how much each process is writing (assuming your OS is POSIX-compliant in this regard). From [`write()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html#tag_16_685):

> Write requests to a pipe or FIFO shall be handled in the same way as a regular file with the following exceptions:
>   [...]
>
> - Write requests of {PIPE_BUF} bytes or less **shall not be interleaved** with data from other processes doing writes on the same pipe. Writes of greater than {PIPE_BUF} bytes may have data interleaved, on arbitrary boundaries, with writes by other processes, whether or not the O_NONBLOCK flag of the file status flags is set.

Also in the [*Rationale* section](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html#tag_16_685_08) regarding pipes and FIFOs:

> - *Atomic/non-atomic*: A write is atomic if the whole amount written in one operation is not interleaved with data from any other process. This is useful when there are multiple writers sending data to a single reader. Applications need to know how large a write request can be expected to be performed atomically. This maximum is called {PIPE_BUF}. This volume of POSIX.1-2008 does not say whether write requests for more than {PIPE_BUF} bytes are atomic, but requires that writes of {PIPE_BUF} or fewer bytes shall be atomic.

The value if `PIPE_BUF` is defined by each implementation, but the minimum is 512 bytes (see [`limits.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html)). On Linux, it's 4096 bytes (see [`pipe(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)).

Comment: PIPE_BUF is, by the way, guaranteed to be at least 512. Note that you also have to guarantee that your process _actually_ writes each line to it in a single write call. Enabling line buffering (`setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOLBF,512)`) will do this without requiring you to use low-level functions.

Comment: Here's a table of observed `PIPE_BUF` values on common Unix systems: http://ar.to/notes/posix#pipe-buf

Comment: I don't understand how sockets can be multiplexed...but named pipes can't?? everything on unix is just a file right? lulz

Comment: @AlexanderMills: I don't understand your comment

Comment: @Mat I think you mean "maximum is 512 bytes" not "minimum is 512 bytes"

Comment: @AlexanderMills: no, that's the minimum value

Comment: The spec says that up to PIPE_BUF bytes can be written atomically and will not be interleaved with any other writer. And PIPE_BUF is guaranteed to be a number that is 512 or more.

Comment: What about READ? when  a process reads, the whole content is read and if other process tries to read while the other is reading, the reading will be blocked for the second process?

Comment: @Samuel!: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html "The behavior of multiple concurrent reads on the same pipe, FIFO, or terminal device is unspecified."