# Multiplex multiple streams in to single stream - Bash

Tags: bash

I had this question for some time now.

***Scenario***
What I want to do is run a program with a CLI. this program accepts one command at a time and execute it. Most the time these commands goes in batches. So catting a list of command at ones on one stream is going to work great but I also want to intervene manually time to time by sending some additional commands through the keyboard.

***My attempt to resolve it***
I used one named pipe as below and used redirecting them all to the same file descriptor as follows.

FIFO

```
$ mkfifo /tmp/testpipe
$ mknod /tmp/testpipe p
```

Redirection

```
{ cat /tmp/testpipe &
  cat - &
  wait; } | consumer_process
```

[image]

REF: [Is there an opposite of 'tee', to stream multiple pipes together?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364195/is-there-an-opposite-of-tee-to-stream-multiple-pipes-together)

***The problem***
With the setup explained above the first time when I push something in to the named pipe, it works fine as expected, but the second time when I push something to the pipe it doesn't reach the consumer process.

***Failed attempt to fix the issue***
Tried catting the named pipe and echo on  the other end. First time it came through but not the second time.

TERM1

```
cat /tmp/testpipe &
```

TERM2

```
echo "TESTING123" > /tmp/testpipe   --> Received on term 1
echo "TESTING123" > /tmp/testpipe   --> Nothing received on term 1
```

Is there a way to fix this issue or getting this done in an easier way ?

Comment: The problem is that after you do the `echo "TESTING123" > /tmp/testpipe` in `TERM2` there is nothing holding open the write end of /tmp/testpipe. Therefore after the first echo the cat in TERM1 gets EOF. In TERM2 at the start add `sleep 3600 > /tmp/testpipe &` and make sure you do all your work in an hour!

Comment: You wrote the program accepts one command at a time. Are the commands independent enough so they can be processed by separate instances of the program? Or can they be at least grouped to independent packs for separate instances? If so, queuing tasks in task spooler (`ts`, or `tsp` in Debian and like) will allow you to manage the queue and e.g. inject an extra task and mark it as urgent. This is not an answer (yet) because it's not going to work if single instance of the program must process everything. And I don't know if this is not the case.

Comment: Thanks very much for the inputs. As @icarus outlined the fifo is closing as its expected to do so once the first write is finished. I read in another place socat can be used to avoid this. I tried socat /tmp/testpipe - along with cat - but so far couldnt get it working. you guys think its possible to do so with socat ?

Comment: Any program that can keep a file descriptor open is fine, and that includes socat. What is wrong with using `sleep`? if an hour is not enough then there are roughly 10π million second in a year.